# How to get CLSID variable name, like MSVC?

Tags: visual-c++, com, clsid

When you are debugging a program and you hover over a GUID variable, MSVC retrieves both the variable name (e.g. CLSID_FilterGraph) and the human name (e.g. Filter Graph Object).

It does the second by looking at HKCR\CLSID\GUID - but where does it get the variable name from?? It's not in the registry.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The debugging info in the .pdb, probably.  It just needs to iterate the CLSIDs defined in the mumble_i.c file generated by MIDL.  No problem matching them, they are after all globally unique :)

Comment: I thought so - I guess I'll have to settle for the "Human name" - shipping all the .pdbs is not worth the variable name :) Thanks!